# Как убрать стрелки при табуляции?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При табуляции появляются стрелки, как показано на рисунке.

Как настроить Visual Studio Code так, чтобы были только вертикальные линии без стрелок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так (новейшая версия vscode):
Вид -> отображать пробелы или
View -> display spaces

Comment: Spenkau, спассибо большое) Вопрос решён) а Вы не знаете, как сделать вертикальные линии, чтобы отображать вложенность?

Comment: @Hedonist посмотрите это обновление [bracket-guide-improvements](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_bracket-guide-improvements)

Answer (score 0):

я скачал Visual Studio 2022, и там стрелок при табуляции нет. возможно, я как-то настроил по умолчанию так, что стрелок там нет. я сделал ~ 25 проектов, но ни в одном не было стрелок.

Comment: visual studio code  не то же самое, что visual studio